# Vba code to click on next page using firefox

Tags: vba, firefox

I have vba code with the help of this code i am able to click on next page in website using internet explorer but i want this code to work in firefox.

Please find the below code

```html
Dim lis As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim nextLi As HTMLLIElement, n As Long
Set lis = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("LI")
Set nextLi = Nothing
n = 0
While n < lis.Length And nextLi Is Nothing
If lis(n).innerText = "Next" Then Set nextLi = lis(n)
n = n + 1
Wend
If Not nextLi Is Nothing Then
nextLi.Click
End If
```

The code which i have try for firefox

```html
Sub test() 
Dim driver As New Selenium.FirefoxDriver
Dim lis As IHTMLElementCollection 
Dim nextLi As HTMLLIElement, n As Long 
driver.Get "url" 
driver.Timeouts.Server = 120000 
driver.Window.Maximize 
Dim lis As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim nextLi As HTMLLIElement, n As Long
Set lis = driver.findElementsByTagName("LI")
Set nextLi = Nothing
n = 0
While n < lis.Length And nextLi Is Nothing
If lis(n).innerText = "Next" Then Set nextLi = lis(n)
n = n + 1
Wend
If Not nextLi Is Nothing Then
nextLi.Click
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: which part of the program is failing?   you did not post a part of the firefox code.

Comment: Hi Jsotola thanks for the reply actually I am getting error message Run-time error '13'; type mismatch at Set lis = driver.findElementsByTagName("LI")

Comment: where is `driver` declared?

Comment: Hi Jsotola thanks for the reply here is the complete code which i have tried Sub test()
Dim driver As New Selenium.FirefoxDriver
Dim lis As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim nextLi As HTMLLIElement, n As Long
driver.Get "url"
driver.Timeouts.Server = 120000
driver.Window.Maximize
Set lis = driver.findElementsByTagName("LI")
Set nextLi = Nothing
n = 0
While n < lis.Length And nextLi Is Nothing
If lis(n).innerText = "Next" Then Set nextLi = lis(n)
n = n + 1
Wend
If Not nextLi Is Nothing Then
nextLi.Click
End If
End Sub

Comment: please update your question with the code

Comment: Hi jsotola thanks for reply i have updated my code.

Answer (score 1):

The SeleniumBasic open code you are using cannot handle FireFox release 47 and newer.

By asking to the Selenium team, it is also not planned to update SeleniumBasic adding the new FirefoxDriver (now called GeckoDriver).

No way to use the updated FireFox versions by VBA and Selenium following your code.